# UIWebView and javascript need to load data

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a file called proof.html like this one:

```
    <title>{title}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{cssURL}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<body class="{language} {custom}">
<div class="FeedTitle">{feedTitle}<br /><span><em>via</em> RSS</span></div>
<div class="Published">{date}</div>
<div class="Title"><a href="{sourceURL}">{title}</a></div>
<div class="Author">{author}</div>
<div class="RSS">{text}</div>
<div class="Original"><a href="{sourceURL}"></a></div>
```

Later on I am loading it in my UIWebViev using the command below:

```
 [doc loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"proof" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Now I can't understand how I can replace for example {author} with the real name of the autor of my news... How can I pass It to my UIWebView? Can someone share an example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to do this, with the method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

for example:

```
[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('Author').innerHTML = '%@';",authorsName]];
```

note: for the above example, you will need to add an id attribute to your divs.

Comment: mmm I try your code but I can't understand how it works.     NSString *author=@"Sample";
    [doc stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('author').innerHTML = '%@';",author]]; but I'll not able to replace {author] with the "Sample" string.

Comment: the `document.getElementById('author')` will search for the div element in your web page which has an `id`attribute equal to `author`. You must change you HTML to `<div id="author" class="Author">{author}</div>` for it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using javascript.

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your js code"];
```

Above code will evaluate the javascript into ur current page. You can add js code to set the author to ur desired string.

Comment: Thanks I understand but I don't know I can create a funct that can replaced the {author} that I see on my uiwebview. Can you show mw an example?